# Rails: undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

This might be a simple question, but I can't figure it out.

Model `Question` has many Model `Answer`, and they both belong to Model `User`.

Here is part of `index.erb.html`:

```
<tbody>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= question.content %></td>
        <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.email %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Show', question %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

        <% if question.answers %>
          <h4>Answers</h4>
          <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
          <p> 
             <%= answer.content %> 
          </p>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <br>
        <p>Add Answers</p>ww
        <%= form_for([question,question.answers.build]) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :content %>
          <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
          <br>
          <% end %>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

And I used `seed.rb` to insert data.

Here is **seed.rb**

```
User.destroy_all
Question.destroy_all
Answer.destroy_all

user = User.create(email: "123@gmail.com", password: "2wsx1qaz")
q = Question.create(content: "Q1", user: user)
#q2 = Question.create(content: "Q2", user: user)
Answer.create(content:  "answer1", question: q, user: user)
Answer.create(content: "answer2", question: q, user: user)
```

But it threw this error 
[image]

I also put this project on [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/devise-cancancan/)

### Update

After above error, the render result is weird.

It should show Question, and then check there are any answer for that question. If there are, shows answers.

But, the result on my browser is like that

[image]

But, I expected it should be like this

[image]

Comment: i think you need to used `question` instead of `@question`. as per your screenshot on line no 25.

Comment: Oh my gosh, why I miss that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `@question` defined, so it's `nil` and that's why you got: `undefined method answers for nil:NilClass` when you called this:

```
@question.answers
```

You actually have `question` defined. So, use that :-)

Change this:

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
```

To:

```
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. but I found another weird problems, why answers show above question?

Comment: the rendered html looks weird because you put everything in a single table row i.e. the question, their answers, link to `show`, `edit` etc. and even the `Add Answer` form--everything in a single row! I think that's not what you are looking for. I would suggest you to figure out the layout of your page first and how you want to render the output. Your backend logic is fine now and now you just need to render the output in correct format.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is incorrect

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago by <%= question.user.email %>
```

which is outside table data so put this in your `<td>` clause. an your answers are also not in any table data so put it in proper format of table.
 for more info to render table in html [#table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). so it is disturbed your UI part.

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your description, this line is inside table. Why it's outside table definition?

Comment: sorry not actually table definition. its table data `<td>`